# UWP multi-instance vs multiple views

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, multiple-instances, multiple-views

I am working on a tabbed editor with multiple windows. User can open new tabs to edit different files or open a new window to edit different sets of files, also drag and drop across windows is supported. I want to know which approach will be better, should I create multiple instances of the app or should I use multiple views to display different windows. What are the pros and cons of each approach??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific display mode needs to be determined according to the actual usage of your application.

The common design of UWP application is single instance and multiple views. Multi-instance is only for desktop and IOT devices, and there are some restrictions on the background task, the specific content can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/multi-instance-uwp).

In your editor application, you can do different treatments for different situations.

If the user only needs to edit a single file, then create multiple tabs under the current application view. If the user needs to edit or browse multiple files at the same time, you may consider adding a button in the editor so that the user can separate it into a new window.

About the application scenarios of multi-view, there are instructions in this document:

- [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views)

Thanks.

Comment: Does enabling multi-instance disqualifies app to run on platforms other than desktop and iot. Limitation on background task isn't an issue for me.

Comment: Currently the app is implemented so that user can create a new instance of the app by clicking on a button. If they want to open a tab in a new window they can just drag the tab outside the window(just like browsers).

Comment: Due to the use of platform-specific APIs, your application will not be able to use the functions based on this API on other platforms. This means that the full functionality of the application can only be used on desktop and IOT devices (if you publish the package in the Microsoft Store, do not check other platforms except desktop and IOT, otherwise you will not pass the application test)